# Probability of $(0, 0)$ being closer to a point inside square $(11, -9), (29, 9)$ than to a point inside square $(-9, -9), (9, 9)$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Let $p_0$ be a fixed point at $(0, 0)$.
Let $p_1$ be a uniformly distributed random point inside the square $(-9, -9), (9, 9)$,
and let $p_2$ be another random point inside the square $(11, -9), (29, 9)$.

Let $d_1$ be the distance between $p_0$ and $p_1$, and $d_2$ be the distance between $p_0$ and $p_2$. What is the probability of $d_2 < d_1$?

Using a montecarlo simulation I was able to estimate this probability to be arround $0.000394379$, but I would like to know where it comes from.

My attempts to solve this geometrically have failed, but here is a plot for intuition:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSd5W.png)

The two points must lay outside of the small circle, but inside of the bigger one, and still there is a chance that $p_1$ will be closer.

Related questions: 
[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22488/probability-that-uniformly-random-points-in-a-rectangle-have-euclidean-distance)
[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52909/how-to-find-the-expected-distance-between-two-uniformly-distributed-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition $d_2\lt d_1$ can be fulfilled for $11\le d_2\lt d_1\le9\sqrt2$. For $d_1,d_2\in[11,9\sqrt2]$, the measures of the angle ranges that lie within the respective squares are $4(\frac\pi2-2\arccos\frac9{d_1})$ for the first square and $2\arccos\frac{11}{d_2}$ for the second square. Thus the desired probability is

\begin{eqnarray*}
&&\frac8{18^4}\int_{11}^{9\sqrt2}\mathrm dd_1d_1\left(\frac\pi2-2\arccos\frac9{d_1}\right)\int_{11}^{d_1}\mathrm dd_2d_2\arccos\frac{11}{d_2}
\\
&=&
\frac8{2\cdot18^4}\int_{11}^{9\sqrt2}\mathrm dd_1d_1\left(\frac\pi2-2\arccos\frac9{d_1}\right)\left(d_1^2\arccos\frac{11}{d_1}-11d_1\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{11}{d_1}\right)^2}\right)
\\
&\approx&
0.000394374
\end{eqnarray*}

([Wolfram|Alpha computation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=Integrate+%5B4%2F18%5E4+*+x+(pi%2F2+-+2+arccos+(9%2Fx))+(x%5E2+arccos+(11%2Fx)+-+11+x+sqrt(1-+(11%2Fx)%5E2)),x,11,9+sqrt+2%5D)). I don't see how to analytically integrate the term involving both $\arccos\frac9{d_1}$ and $\arccos\frac{11}{d_1}$, and neither does Wolfram|Alpha.